I want to combine four analog inputs into one output using two op amps. Is this feasible?
I'm doing my first project with electronics and I'm trying to figure out how to make an Arduino read input from four identical sensors using one analog pin. I'm using multiplexers on my other sensors, but this last pin is dedicated to leak sensors, and I don't want to cycle through the sensors if I can just pull data from all of them simultaneously. I've been looking into adder circuits and I think I have one that would work, but I was hoping to get some feedback from people who actually know this stuff.
Each sensor will output about 2.5 V when fully submerged in water. I want to add the voltage together and divide it by 4 so that the Arduino never receives voltages over 5 V. Since I need to deamplify the voltage, I figured a non-inverting op amp wouldn't be an option (to my understanding there would always be amplification no matter what the ratio of input/feedback resistors is). The issue with an inverting op amp setup is that its output will be negative, which can't be read by the Arduino. So to return the voltage to a positive level, I thought it might be a good idea to just use another inverting op amp circuit.
The plan is to use the LMV358IDR chip to add the analog voltages and output a quarter of their sum. There should also be a picture of the basic circuit that I have in mind. This is my first project with electronics and there's a LOT of stuff to learn, so any feedback at all would be appreciated.


You can do this with one amplifier. What is the output impedance and range of the sensors?

The range is theoretically 0 to 5 volts but the outputs generally top out at 2.5 volts. As for the impedance, I believe it would be less than an ohm but I’m not positive. The sensor is powered by 5v only draws 20 mA of current when it’s sending a signal.
Could my circuit still work if I just take out the second amplifier? Or would I have to make other changes as well?

If the aim is to determine if there is a ‘leak’ then maybe using diodes such that you read the highest voltage of the four ( or more) inputs. If you add an analog multiplexer as well you can then sample the inputs to determine which one represents the leak.  For the diode solution, join the  cathodes together (the end with the band) and a , say, 10k resistor to 0V. Note you get a voltage drop of around 0.6V across each diode.

It's funny you mention that, I have 16 other sensors hooked up to four multiplexer circuits so that my arduino can read all of them with four pins. The main reason I wanted a different circuit for my leak sensors is that they're meant to put the system into an "emergency off" condition and I wanted the controller to receive input from all four sensors at all times. To be honest though, I'm just over complicating things so that I can learn more about different electrical components and how to make them work. It's really neat stuff that I've never dived into before

Would you mind going into a little more detail on the diode solution? I think I might understand how that would work, but I'm having trouble picturing it

This will work:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The values are for sensors that will span 0V-5V. Resistors will have to be adjusted for 2.5V range. The output is inverted but is simply corrected in Arduino firmware. Obviously, you can only read the sum of all sensors collectively with this approach. If the separate sensors need to be known, some sort of multiplexing needs to take place given only one ADC input on the micro.

Wow that was exactly what I was looking for! I do have a couple follow up questions if you don't mind. Can arduinos read any inverted input as long as it's greater than -5V? I read online that they can't read negative voltage, but there's a good chance that I'm misunderstanding. Also, I did some further research and I don't think that my original circuit wouldn't have worked at all. I have 5v and GND powering my op amp rather than 5v and -5v. Does the resistor and capacitor address that issue or are they for something else? Thanks a lot for the help

@plshelpadummy The output being inverted doesn't necessarily mean it will be negative. The supply rails for the op-amp shown are GND and +5V, so the output can only be between 0V and 5V. In this case inverted means if the combined input is 0V, the output will be 5V, and vice versa. This is because the + input is biased to 2.5V through R2/R3, so a 2.5V input corresponds to a 2.5V output.

Ah, that makes sense. I think I'll have to do quite a bit more research on biasing before moving forward but you definitely helped make things a bit clearer. Thanks

@plshelpadummy To add to what Tom said, when I said "inverted" I meant that the sensor transfer function was inverted - the opamp output has a negative slope with respect to the senor input. Since you are using this as a leak detector, you can actually change the sensitivity by changing R8. For this application, it doesn't matter if you saturate the amplifier. TBH, you might not need the amplifier at all - you could just feed all the sensor through resistors into the ADC input if your sensors are sensitive enough to the leak detection.
